# contenteditable binding for KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, html, data-binding, knockout.js, contenteditable

I 'm currently trying to implement a custom KnockoutJS binding to make a div contenteditable. As an example, I'll take the ViewModel from the first tutorial at knockoutJS and add a "edit mode"-flag:

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/ejugip/3/edit

ViewModel Code:

```
function HelloWorldViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.isInEditMode = ko.observable(true);
    self.firstName = ko.observable('Bert');
    self.lastName = ko.observable('Berntington');
    self.fullName = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.firstName() + ' ' + self.lastName();
    });
}
```

View Code:

```
<fieldset id="HelloWorldView">  
    <legend>Hello World</legend>
    <p><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isInEditMode" /> edit mode</p>
    <label>First name:</label>
    <div data-bind="contenteditable: isInEditMode, text: firstName"></div>
    <label>Last name:</label>
    <div data-bind="contenteditable: isInEditMode, text: lastName"></div>
    <label>Full name:</label>
    <div data-bind="text: fullName"></div>
</fieldset>
```

This is my binding handler code, so far:

```
function makeEditable(element, editable) {
    $(element).attr('contenteditable', (editable) ? true : false);
    $(element).removeClass('Editable');
    if (editable) {
        $(element).addClass('Editable');
    }
}

ko.bindingHandlers.contenteditable = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {},
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var editable = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        makeEditable(element, editable);
    }
};
```

For now, I'm just adding the contenteditable attribute to the element and a css class.

So entering and leaving the edit mode works fine. One thing that's still missing is, that the viewModel gets updated after the contenteditable elements are edited.

What's the best way to get the viewmodel in sync with my editable elements? Do I need an own custom "text:" binding, or is there an easier way?

Comment: This thread: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/knockoutjs/Mh0w_cEMqOk/discussion and this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/JksKx/ might help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some time ago I created a KO based contenteditable binding plus editor that you can maybe get some inspiration from.

https://github.com/madcapnmckay/Knockout-UI/blob/master/js/ui-editor.js

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. It's a little neglected, really need to find some time to update it and tidy it up.

Comment: Although it's a bit neglected, it's a great start to learn more about how knockout's custom binding handlers can be used. I'm still a koJS-newbie :)